# State updated only after second button press

Tags: react-native, redux, fetch, state

I'm trying to learn some react native and I encontered a problem.
I want to make a login. I'm sending the email and password to a server with post fetch and I receive a json answer. Now my problem is that when I press the button and I want to get the result from the api it is empty (see the yellow marked zone). It will get a value only after I press the second time the button.
[image]

I will put pieces of code to see what I did:

I have the button with onPress property

```
<Button
    title="Autentificare"
    buttonStyle={styles.button}
    onPress={getAuth}
/>
```

The function called when I press the button

```
const getAuth = () => {
    console.log("before dispatch");
    dispatch(sendAuth(email, pass)).then(function () {
        console.log("before processInfo");
        processInfo();
        console.log("after processInfo");
    });

}

const processInfo = () => {
    console.log("here");
    console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
    if (result.loggedIn == "true") { ....
```

get redux state

```
const { result, email, pass } = useSelector(state => state.userReducer);
console.log("result before: " + JSON.stringify(result));
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

in actions.js

```
export const sendAuth = (name, password) => {
    try {
        return async dispatch => {
            const result = await fetch(API_URL, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                mode: 'cors',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  "name": name,
                  "password": password
                })
            });
            console.log("name: " + name);
            const json = await result.json();
            
            if (json) {
                dispatch({
                    type: SEND_AUTH,
                    payload: json
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Unable to fetch!');
            }
            console.log("json: " + API_URL + " | " + JSON.stringify(json));

            
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

in reducers.js

```
function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER_NAME:
            return { ...state, email: action.payload };
        case SET_USER_PASS:
            return { ...state, pass: action.payload };
        case SEND_AUTH:
            console.log("action.payload: " +  JSON.stringify(action.payload));
            return { ...state, result: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default userReducer;
```

After I press the second time the login button logs looks like this:
[image]

Thank you and I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

in actions I returned the json and in dispatch I did something like this:

```
dispatch(sendAuth(email, pass)).then((response) => {
    console.log("response:" + JSON.stringify(response));
    if (response.loggedIn == 'true') { ....
```

And I used the response to process information further